# Replace text in Rich text area field with trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects, string

We're using the "Solutions" standard object as our knowledge base, with "Solution details" standard field is a Rich Text Area field (32000 characters).

The field structure looks like this:

Purpose (header 1)

text..

Appropriate versions (Header 2)

text: version numbers.

Additional Details (Header 3)

text..

What I want to do is update the text under "header 2" without the need to enter to each solution and field and type the versions manually. I created a custom picklist field called "versions", and tried copying the picklist value into the "Solution details" field via workflow rule and field update - the problem is that it causes losing all HTML and turns this field to text only. I understood it's possible to update this without loosing HTML only with trigger. Did anyone accomplished something similar? are there even "Substitute" / "replace" functions in triggers??

Comment: For anyone working on richtext and not understanding why code is required, workflow field updates and formulas don't work on rich text fields.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, APEX, the language used to write triggers, supports find and replace.  String types (which include rich-text fields) have a number of options, primarily `String.replace()` and `String.replaceAll()` (see the [String methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_string.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) for the full list).  You also use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes that can do more complex regex related activities (see the [Pattern and Matcher docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)).

**Basic Example**

```
trigger YourTrigger on Solution (before update) {   
  for(Solution s : trigger.new) {
    s.replaceAll('Hello World','Goodbye World');
  }
}
```

**More Info**

If you're looking to explore what other functionality is available, you'll want to have the [APEX API Reference handy](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm).

Comment: thanks @ralph, can you share an example of how to find a string within two strings? (In this case it is Header 2 and 3)

Comment: take a look at indexOf in the string methods link in the answer, i think that's what you're looking for